# KivyMD MDRectangleFlatIconButton's text is in two lines when text is updated with a long text

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to update MDRectangleFlatIconButton's text. It changes with a new text but when the new text is longer than previous text, then the text fits in two lines.
When i use a normal button, the new text fits in one line with proper adjustment.

but Since there is a Icon in MDRectangleFlatIconButton, when a new text is longer than previous text, the text fits in a two line.

To run the program,
Add a new app name which is longer than "Info" inside "Info" button's popup window, then click "Update Top Bar's name". Then, it updated title and the text of "Info" button at the front main App.

I have tried to change this by adding button's text_size: self.width, valign:"center", haling: "center", or manually adding text_size: cm(10), cm(10).
Also, i tried with on_release: "app.root.ids.bt_information.text_size = self.width, None

but nothing works so far.

I greatly appreciate your help.

Python code

'''

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
'''Setting the size of first window for program'''
from kivy.config import Config                 #another way of setting size of window
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')         # from kivy.core.window import Window
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '750')        # Window.size = ("600", "750")

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_file('new_window_popup.kv')

class Dex(Popup):
    pass
    
class Remi(Popup):
    pass

class Info(Popup):
    pass

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
class AwesomeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "My house"
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

'''

kivyfile: new_window_popup.kv

'''

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button

<Dex>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Weight-Based Dose Calculator "   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Dex 1" 
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()    
    
<Remi>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Weight-Based Dose Calculator "   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Remi" 
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<Info>:

    appName:appName
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Change Info"   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "What is your App name?" 
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            
            MDTextField:
                id: appName
                hint_text: "App Name"
                color_mode: 'primary'
                current_hint_text_color: 1,1,1,1
                hint_text_color_focus: 1,1,1,.9 
                line_color_focus: 1,1,1,1
                font_size: '25sp'
                text_color_normal: 1,1,1,.9
                text_color_focus: 0,0,1,.9
                focus: True
                write_tab: False
            Button:
                text: "Update Top Bar\'s name"
                font_size: 24
                size_hint: .8, .2
                # on_release: root.updateName()    
                on_release: 
                    app.title = appName.text
                    app.root.ids.bt_information.text = appName.text
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<MyLayout>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Dex"
            font_size: 32
            text_color: 0,0,0,.9
            size_hint: 1,.5
            on_press: Factory.Dex().open()
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Remi"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1,.5
            on_press: Factory.Remi().open()
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            id: bt_information
            text: "Info"
            icon: "youtube-studio"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1,.2
            text_size: self.width, None
            md_bg_color: 0.95,0.61,0.73,1
            on_press: Factory.Info().open()
```

'''

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (meaning text always fits in one line no matter how long it is). What version of `KivyMD` are you using ?

Comment: Hi. ApuCoder. python 3.10.4 KivyMD1.0.0.dev0  kivy2.1.0.  

When you put a new name of App and click up "Update Top Bar Name" and then, click click button to get back to the front App. Then the bottom button of front main app's text is also changed. But when the new app's name is longer than the previous name of this button, it becomes in two lines.

Comment: For example, the initial word is "Info" , if i put a new App name like "Info12" , click"Update Top Bar Name" - "Close" . Then it go back to the front of this App, then it looks like this. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13PVx6rK7MQO42uQ7vISbIZkdyBioZ9_P/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "Info12" is in two lines. I wish this "Info12" stays in one line. I appreciate your effort. Thanks.